# while() loop does not break even with valid input

Tags: r

I was following a Youtube video that was going through how to create an interactive menu in R. I did tweak some stuff from the original video, but nothing drastic that would make or break the code (at least I think so).

The youtube video I watched:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaPBpJArh0M

The menu popped up, and I tried putting in non-zero values. What I expected to happen was that entering "1" would give the following message:

```
1. Binomial
2. Poisson
3. Geometric
4. Negative Binomial
5. Hypergeometric
6. Uniform
7. Normal
8. Exponential
Please choose a menu item: 1
Good choice!
```

Choosing any other non zero number would give the following message instead:

```
1. Binomial
2. Poisson
3. Geometric
4. Negative Binomial
5. Hypergeometric
6. Uniform
7. Normal
8. Exponential
Please choose a menu item: 2
Bad choice.
```

And choosing any other output like 0 or any non-integer would bring back the "Please choose a menu item" message:

'''
Please choose a menu item: 0
Please choose a menu item: s
'''

However, despite having valid inputs of non-zero values, the loop continued breaking.

```
Please choose a menu item: 1
Please choose a menu item: 2
Please choose a menu item: 3
Please choose a menu item: 4
Please choose a menu item: 5
Please choose a menu item: 6
Please choose a menu item: 7
```

The specific function that seems to be acting up is this part of the code:

```
inputNumber <- function(prompt) {
  # Usage: num = inputNumber(prompt)
  # 
  # Displays prompt and asks for a number. 
  # Repeats until user inputs a valid number.
  while(TRUE) {
    num = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(readline(prompt)))
    if(!is.na(num)) {
      break
    }
  }
}

displayMenu <- function(options) {
  # Usage: choice = displayMenu(options)
  # 
  # Displays a menu of options,
  # ask the user to choose an item,
  # and return the number of the menu item chosen.
  # 
  # Input   options   Menu options (cell array of strings)
  # Output  choice    Chosen option (integer)

  # Display menu options
  for (i in 1:length(options)) {
    cat(sprintf("%d. %s\n", i, options[i]))
  }

  # Gets a valid menu choice
  choice <- 0
  while (!any(choice == 1:length(options))) {
    choice = inputNumber("Please choose a menu item: ")
  }

  return(choice)
}

# Define menu options
menuItems   <- c("Binomial", "Poisson", "Geometric", "Negative Binomial", "Hypergeometric", "Uniform", "Normal", "Exponential")

  # Displays the menu
  choice <- displayMenu(menuItems)

  if(choice == 1) {
    print("Good choice!")
  } else {
    print("Bad choice.")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `inputNumber` function is not returning anything, you just break it without assign it a value. Use `return` instead, which will stop the while and return a value to the function call.

```
inputNumber <- function(prompt) {
  # Usage: num = inputNumber(prompt)
  # 
  # Displays prompt and asks for a number. 
  # Repeats until user inputs a valid number.
  while(TRUE) {
    num = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(readline(prompt)))
    if(!is.na(num)) {
      return(num)
    }
  }
}

displayMenu <- function(options) {
  # Usage: choice = displayMenu(options)
  # 
  # Displays a menu of options,
  # ask the user to choose an item,
  # and return the number of the menu item chosen.
  # 
  # Input   options   Menu options (cell array of strings)
  # Output  choice    Chosen option (integer)

  # Display menu options
  for (i in 1:length(options)) {
    cat(sprintf("%d. %s\n", i, options[i]))
  }

  # Gets a valid menu choice
  choice <- 0
  while (!any(choice == 1:length(options))) {
    choice = inputNumber("Please choose a menu item: ")
  }

  return(choice)
}

# Define menu options
menuItems   <- c("Binomial", "Poisson", "Geometric", "Negative Binomial", "Hypergeometric", "Uniform", "Normal", "Exponential")

# Displays the menu
choice <- displayMenu(menuItems)

if(choice == 1) {
  print("Good choice!")
} else {
  print("Bad choice.")
}
```